# Swift: View position resets when app is minimized, then brough back to foreground

Tags: swift, xcode, io, uikit

I have a UIView that starts off in a random position (set up through storyboard), then finds its actual position when `viewDidLoad()` is called, depending on the user preferences stored in `UserDefaults`.

The problem is when the app is minimized, and then brought back to the foreground, the position of that UIView resets to the initial random position.
How could I prevent the app from releasing that position determined at runtime? Or do I need to re-calculate that position through a function that is triggered when the app is brought back from being inactive?

I don't think there is much use to include code for this, but the position of the UIView (named 'contextUnderscoreLine') is set in `viewDidLoad()` with `contextUnderscoreLine.center = savedCGPoint`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution for this, in case someone else was going through the same issue:

Add an observer in `viewDidLoad()` to detect when the application is 'active'. From documentation, my understanding is that this will get called once when the app is launched, and then every time the app comes back from being in the background. So the initial formatting of the problematic UIView can be done there instead of in `viewDidLoad()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationDidBecomeActive), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func applicationDidBecomeActive(notification: NSNotification) {
    // Application is back in the foreground

    //determine the position of the UIView here, instead of in viewDidLoad()
}
```

### Edit

For my specific case it was better to use `UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification` instead of `UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification`. That way the changes in UIView are done before the Application is back in the foreground, and therefore you avoid the noticeable UIView jitters as the changes are made in front of the user.